# Using SSIS at run-time how do you create a destination table in SQL Server based off a source table structure from Oracle?

Tags: sql, ssis, ssms

Using SSIS at run-time how do you create a destination table in SQL Server (with the right number of fields, names, data types etc.) solely based off a source table structure from Oracle? The reason for asking is my Oracle tables often changes structure (fields added, data types changed etc.) and my package breaks if there is a mismatch say between the number of source and destination table fields. I need to automate this as I am scheduling packages to run as jobs in SSMS. I have looked everywhere and tried everything but cannot find a suitable solution to this problem....however I'm sure it is possible...somehow.

Comment: I'd look at using a Script task to analyze the Oracle table, and populate a string variable with a CREATE TABLE statement that I could then execute with an Execute SQL task.

Comment: You don't. That is special table creating sauce that is only available during the development process. There is no native API that I'm aware of that allows you to create a table during runtime. And why would you want to do so - the data flow task would have to have the metadata set before it begins validation, which is well before data begins flowing through the pipeline.

Comment: So maybe not at run-time. However if a field is added to one of the oracle tables I'm pulling over, then the nightly refresh to SQL server fails because it doesn't have "that extra field" in its table. So I would like to drop the table (instead of just truncating it), re-create it using the oracle table as a source and then load it. Is this possible?

Comment: You can do pretty much anything with a script task.

Comment: Tab: How do you map an oracle table's data types to the data types of a MSSQL server table's? Can you do that with a script? If yes, could you write an example?